# invalid type promotion when doing np.where field is date type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, date

So I have a data set of prices and days for a list of stocks.

The data is sorted by stock ticker and then date

For each row, I want to be able to get the closing price on the next date as well as the next date.  In the case where the symbols are different, I want null values.  It works for the date field as long as the date is an object type but results in an invalid type promotion if the field is a datetime type.

So for example

```
Symbol   Date          Price

A        2020-01-01  50

A        2020-01-02  51

B        2020-01-01  101
```

I would want the NextClose field to be 51 for the first record and the NextDate value to be 2020-12-02

For the second record, I would want both values to be null because the symbol changes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02","2020-01-03"],
                   "Symbol": ["A","A","B"],
                   "Price": [50, 51, 101]})


/*this works */

df['NextClose']=np.where(df['Symbol'] ==df ['Symbol'].shift(-1),df ['Price'].shift(-1).round(4),np.nan)
df['NextDate']=np.where(df['Symbol'] ==df ['Symbol'].shift(-1),df ['Date'].shift(-1),np.nan)
 
/* this gives the invalid type promotion error */

df["NewDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df['NextNewDate']=np.where(df['Symbol'] ==df ['Symbol'].shift(-1),df ['NewDate'].shift(-1),np.nan)
```

Any idea what I can do to populate the NextClose field with a null value when the field is a datetime type?

Thanks

Note:

```
df['NextNewDate']=np.where(df['Symbol'] ==df ['Symbol'].shift(-1),df ['NewDate'].shift(-1),pd.NaT)
```

Does not throw off an error, but returns the result in epoch time  (1577923200000000000)

```
df['NextNewDate']=pd.to_datetime(df["NextNewDate"])
```

Adding this after returns the right date, but it seems to be an extra step

Comment: Could you put in a small section of code making your data, so that we know the types of the columns, `np.nan` looks like its not a datetime.  `pd.NaT` is what you want....

Comment: So this sort of works  df['NextNewDate']=np.where(df['Symbol'] ==df ['Symbol'].shift(-1),df ['NewDate'].shift(-1),pd.NaT) will not throw off an error.  However, the resulting value comes out as epoch time i.e. "1577923200000000000" .  A conversion using pd.to_datetime after the fact converts it to a date, but that seems more difficult than it should be... Thanks